# Multidimensional Area and Volume

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry, spacetime-dimensions, integration, volume

In 3D the volume is $xyz$, the product of three coordinates. But in $N$ dimension ,how to define area and volume?

Comment: Volume is easy: it's the product of all dimensions of a hyperbrick. "Area" is not obvious because there are more such quantities, depending on how many dimensions you leave out and you need to understand how to count the "sides" of the hyperbrick. For the hypercube see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/442349/

Comment: We can generalize a volume or area to higher dimensional space by using differential forms. See, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form.

Answer (score 0):

The volume for a 'brick' (also called a hyperrectangle or a box) would be $X1 * X2 *...* Xn$. That is, it is the product of lengths of the coordinates along each of the n dimensions. Volumes in n dimensional spaces are also commonly given as volumes of n dimensional spheres--but that does not lead as cleanly to the definition of n dimensional area.

The area of a plane orthogonal to $Xn$ (i.e. having zero length along dimension $Xn$) would be $X1 * X2 * X3 *...* Xn-1$.  And the area of a plane orthogonal to some other coordinate $Xq$ would be $X1 * X2 * X3 *...* Xq-1 *...* Xq+1 *...* Xn$.  These planes are known as hyperplanes.

Comment: I actually don't think that's right; this has to be done with differential forms as suggested by @Minkyu

Comment: That would be a more advanced response--but it looked to me that the OP was looking (by his wording) for something more straight forward. :)

Comment: i.e. Euclidean space.

Answer (score 0):

If you define area as 2D and volume as 3D, then the problem doesn't make much sense in higher dimensions without clear parameters, such as surface-area of 3D object (like a baseball), can be measured in area (2D).

If we define volume as "n"D not 3D, which is generally assumed then it's straight forward multiplication (for n-cubes/n-rectangles where all angles are 90 degrees).  For those, you multiply each dimension to get the n-volume.

For more exotic shapes like *n-diamonds, n-pyramids, n-polyhedron* it gets quite a bit more complicated, and it's a mathematical exercise, but not of much use.   A bit of info on that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope).

For n-spheres or n-balls, the [calculation are listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball), but a sphere is a pretty simple shape.  I heard in grad-school that n-ball mathematics does have practical use in manufacturing, the 4-sphere specifically.

As others have said, it's a mathematical question, not physics and generally pretty straight forward, unless you have a specific question.